# +99How can i count repeated numbers in a float scanf

Tags: c, count, scanf, repeat

I have a "scanf" scanning a float value being repeated as many times as you want, how can i get the most repeated number at the end of the day?

I thought about using a big array but i still cant use them in my class.

thank you in advance.

Comment: Adding labels such as language you are using will be appreciated by people for a better answer. I think you are using C but just I'm guessing it. Also you can add a sample code reproducing your issue.

Comment: thanks its C as you said

Answer (score -1):

Do you want to see which algarism (0-9) was repeated more or the whole number e.g. 1827.91828? if it is the former, you could create 10 vars like number1, number2, number3.. and so on and incrementing each one when you receive that algarism but if it is the latter, I can´t see another way than using arrays.